# How to exclude myself from Google Website Optimizer results?

Tags: google-analytics, google-website-optimizer

I have a website on which I run Google Website Optimizer (A/B tests) and Google Analytics.

We have automated tests that check some web pages and I am worried that this might interfere with Google Website Optimizer. I have added a filter to Google Analytics, so that Analytics will not track clicks that come from my own IP address. Can I do the same for Google Website Optimizer? How?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can install [Google Analytics Opt-Out](http://tools.google.com/dlpage/gaoptout) on your browser. Since GWO runs off of the Google Analytics script, [it will show variations](http://www.google.com/support/analytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=181881) but will not send to the data to GWO.

FWIW, GWO will only count you *once* per browser. In other words, if you visit your experiment a dozen times from Chrome, it will still only count you once.

Important to note that this will disable *all* Google Analytics trackers for the browser you use it on, so you might want to disable it once you're done worrying about GWO.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer, @yc01.

The script is run in a controlled environment. The cookies are cleared after every run. I suspect Google Analytics uses cookies to identify browsers.

Comment: @Philippe You are correct.